# Fading-in text on page load

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to fade it text on page load, but for some reason the effect does not work at all.
I don't know if it's because something is wrong with the jQuery/CSS, or if it's because I'm not fetching the file correctly.

Here' the HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div class="left-home">
        <div class="left-container">
            <div id="side-one">
                <p>AquaMassage</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-home">
        <div class="right-container">
            <div id="side2">
                <p>Manicure Express</p>
            </div>
            <div class="main-button"><a href="google.com">Enter</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
    body {
    width:100%;
    margin:0;

}

.left-home {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    background:#42C0FB;
    height:963px;

}

.left-container {
    width:60%;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}

.right-home {
    width:50%;
    float:right;
    background:#FFF;
    height:963px;
}

.right-container {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:65%;
    text-align:center;
}

/* 


Side One Below 


*/

#side-one {

    color:#000;
    text-align: center;
}

#side-one p {
    font-size:60px;
    opacity: 0;
}



#side2 {
    padding-top: 130px;
    font-size:60px;
    color:#F660AB;
}




.main-button {
    margin-top:60%;
}

.main-button a {
    background-color: #F660AB;
    border: #F5409A;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #F5409A;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #F5409A;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #F5409A;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 6px 0 7px 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 150px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.main-button a:hover{

}
```

the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#side-one p").delay(1000).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 700);
});
```

I can't seem to find the problem. Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: There is a function in JQuery called `fadeOut()`, and another one `fadeTo()`...

Comment: Works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/H3aPk/1/

Comment: code works for me in fiddle

Comment: I would recommend loading your scripts files at the bottom of your HTML body. To make sure to loads your HTML and CSS first. If your JavaScript runs into any errors it will not be a blank page.

Comment: why every answer is voted down

Comment: Some error on the Console?

Comment: Works fine in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/38pem/), except I changed the text color because the background in the fiddle is white. Perhaps your "scripts.js" file is not getting included. Do you have the correct name and location?

Comment: I put it in the root of the folder, and it still doesn't load. I'm trying to locate the problem. I'm testing it locally.

Comment: _"I'm testing it locally."_ If this is the case, change `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js` to `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js`

Comment: Still not working. Could it be an encoding error?

Comment: The CSS you show cannot be the entire "style.css" file; otherwise your background would be white, not blue. Is there also more in your "scripts.js" file than you are showing? I created three files locally with what you have in the question. I first got the error "ReferenceError: $ is not defined" so I added "http:" as suggested by j08691. Then the animation worked, but I couldn't see it because the text is white. Therefore, I would assume the issue is with something you are not showing.

Comment: Yes, that was only part of the CSS. I've updated the file to show the whole stylesheet.